# How can we wait for multi queue in consumer/producer mode?

Tags: c, mutex

Suppose we have queue sturct like:

```c
typedef struct {
    buffer_t* buffer;

    int empty;
    int full;
    
    pthread_mutex_t lock;
    pthread_cond_t queue_full;
    pthread_cond_t queue_empty;
} queue;
```

If there are two queues, maybe queue01 an queue02, and some consumers and producers works on them.
Can we implement a consumer works on both queues(without create new thread), some pseudo code like:

```c
while(queue01->empty && queue02->empty){
    pthread_cond_wait(&(queue01->queue_full), &(queue01->lock))  \
    || pthread_cond_wait(&(queue02->queue_full), &(queue02->lock));
    // ... do some work with queue01's or queue02's lock
}
```

The code is simplified from real problem, we do not want to merge queues into one.

The target is to wait for multiple queues, we can change code struct or consumers/producers code.

One idea is add a list of pthread_cond_t into queue struct, each consumer add it's private pthread_cond_t var into list, and then consumer just wait it's private pthread_cond_t. Producers need to notify pthread_cond_t in the list  when they notify queue_full, and consumer loop to check every queue cares.